# Electric potential of a sphere at a point on its surface

Tags: electrostatics, electricity, calculus

I'm struggling to figure out how to determine the infinitesimal area of the sphere given in the question.  More specifically, in part (b) of the question.  For part (a) it's the volume so $$V = \frac{4}{3}\pi r^3 $$, therefore, $$dV = 4\pi\ r^2 dr$$.  For part (b), I don't understand why the sine in the equation or how they get that area.  Please see images attached below.  By the way, the problem is from Purcell's 3rd edition.

Question

[image]

Solution

[image]

The equation
\begin{equation}
\phi\left(x,y,z\right) = \int_{\text{all sources}}\dfrac{\rho\left(x^{\prime},y^{\prime},z^{\prime}\right)dx^{\prime}dy^{\prime}dz^{\prime}}{4\pi\epsilon_{o} r}
\tag{2.18}
\end{equation}

Comment: Please embed the images! You can upload images to stackexchange from your hard drive through the prompt brought up when you click the image icon in a post. The dropbox link isn't suitable for embedding.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The area element of the surface of a sphere is $\sin(\theta) r^2 d\theta d\varphi$. You can verify this yourself: $$\int_0^{2\pi}\int_0^\pi \sin(\theta)r^2 d\theta d\varphi=(2\pi)(-\cos(\pi)-(-\cos(0)))=4\pi r^2$$.

So, if you integrate over only the $\varphi$ direction, you get the area of an infinitesimal loop:

$$\int_{\varphi=0}^{\varphi=2\pi}\sin(\theta)r^2 d\theta d\varphi=2\pi r^2 \sin(\theta)d\theta$$

The formula should make sense to you. When $\theta=0$, you expect the loop area to be zero (the loop shrinks down to a point at the pole). When $\theta=\frac{\pi}{2}$, the loop has its maximum size, and at $\theta=\pi$ the loop shrinks back down to a point.

You may want to review some vector calculus for surfaces of revolution, area elements on arbitrary surfaces and on surfaces of revolution, and volume elements in different coordinate systems.

Comment: Thanks a lot, I thought about using that but it didn't make sense to me.  Your answer makes a lot of sense, and I will definitely go review my mathematics, I really appreciate the help.